# How to modify a file in assets folder in a signed apk

Tags: android, apk, assets

I want to modify a file in the assets folder in a signed apk file.
I tried to modify it directly via winrar, but it couldn't be installed again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason for why the APK is signed. 
Though you can try [this](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/12/23/modify-apk-files/) method and see if it works